# Dynamic content not loading in React class that is extending component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to React and I'm trying to load in my content that is being fetched from an API. Normally I use `export default function About({ posts })` and it loads my content, but for 1 of my pages I'm using `export default class BlogPost extends Component {` and don't know where I can put my ({posts}) here. I have tried the following, but it still does not load my dynamic content.

```
export default class BlogPost extends Component {
  constructor(posts) {
    super(posts);
    this.renderTitle = this.renderTitle.bind(this);
  }

  renderTitle() {
    return <div>{posts.Title}</div>;
  }

  render() {
    var settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 4,
      initialSlide: 0,
      nextArrow: <SampleNextArrow />,
      prevArrow: <SamplePrevArrow />,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            infinite: true,
            dots: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    };

    return (
      <>
          <div>
            {this.renderTitle}
          </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

// Tell nextjs how many pages are there
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/blogs");
  const posts = await res.json();

  const paths = posts.map((blog) => ({
    params: { id: blog.id.toString() },
  }));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

// Get data for each individual page
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const { id } = params;

  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:1337/blogs?id=${id}`);
  const data = await res.json();
  const post = data[0];

  return {
    props: { post },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class is using props with `this.props`. So you can update like this to use `posts`

```
export default class BlogPost extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderTitle = this.renderTitle.bind(this);
  }

  renderTitle() {
    return <div>{this.props.posts.Title}</div>;
  }
```

`getStaticProps` return an object of props, so update like this:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  ...
  return {
    post,
  };
}
```

And you also need to call funtion `this.renderTitle`:

```
{this.renderTitle()}
```

Comment: This still didn't load my content. I also tried removing the renderTitle() function and directly putting `{this.props.posts.Title}` in my div tag below and it gave me this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Title' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Any arguments that are coming from parent component are called props and are available in this.props statement of a class component.

Now in your class component you're using posts as argument in super, rather it should be props, same for class. As well you need to run your function in order it to return JSX

```
export default class BlogPost extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderTitle = this.renderTitle.bind(this);
  }

  renderTitle() {
    return <div>{this.props.posts.Title}</div>;
  }

  render() {
    var settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 4,
      initialSlide: 0,
      nextArrow: <SampleNextArrow />,
      prevArrow: <SamplePrevArrow />,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            infinite: true,
            dots: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    };

    return (
      <>
          <div>
            {this.renderTitle()} //run the function as well
          </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

// Tell nextjs how many pages are there
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/blogs");
  const posts = await res.json();

  const paths = posts.map((blog) => ({
    params: { id: blog.id.toString() },
  }));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

// Get data for each individual page
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const { id } = params;

  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:1337/blogs?id=${id}`);
  const data = await res.json();
  const posts = data[0]; //props name should be same

  return {
    posts, //this will act as props
  };
}
```